# difference with/out & sign in subscript function (operator[]) inside class?

Tags: c++

I am starting out learning C++ programming and I just read about "operator[]". This is my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                  
#include <iostream>                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                  
class cls {                                                                                                         
public:                                                                                                             
    cls(int s) {                                                                                                        
        elem = new double[s];                                                                                           
        sz = s;                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                               
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {                                                                                           
            elem[i] = (double)i;                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                     
    double& operator[](int i) {                                                                                                                       
        return elem[i];                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                          
private:                                                                                                                                                  
    double* elem;                                                                                                                                         
    int sz;                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                          
int main() {                                                                                                                                              
    cls some_class(5);                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                          
    std::cout << some_class[2] << std::endl;                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

but it produces the same output as:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                  
#include <iostream>                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
class cls {                                                                                                         
public:                                                                                                             
    cls(int s) {                                                                                                        
        elem = new double[s];                                                                                           
        sz = s;                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                               
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {                                                                                           
            elem[i] = (double)i;                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                     
    double operator[](int i) {                                                                                                                       
        return elem[i];                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                          
private:                                                                                                                                                  
    double* elem;                                                                                                                                         
    int sz;                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                          
int main() {                                                                                                                                              
    cls some_class(5);                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                          
    std::cout << some_class[2] << std::endl;                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

What difference does the '&' do after "double" and before "operator[]"? I get that it should return a reference of type double in the first example and just a double in the second, but why do I get the same answer? Shouldn't one of them fail? Or return a memory address?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
std::cout << some_class[2] << std::endl;      

some_class[2]=4;

std::cout << some_class[2] << std::endl;    

some_class[2]=6;

std::cout << some_class[2] << std::endl;
```

You should now see a difference depending upon whether the overloaded `[]` returns a reference, or not.

Assignment to a reference assigns to the referenced object.

Without a reference effectively a copy of the original object gets returned. Assigning to it (if that's possible, in some situations it's not) does absolutely nothing to the original object.

P.S.:

```
elem[i] = (double)i;
```

The explicit `(double)` is not needed, and should make no difference.